# select2 dropdown not updating the model value in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We have used select2 Jquery plugin for my dropdown and it is used inside ng-template.When a user selects from the select2 dropdown the model used in the angular is not updated.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
<td>{{item.CompanyName}}</td>
<td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
<td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
<td>{{item.UserName}}</td>      
<td style="width:30%;">
    <select multiple data-select-two data-allowclear="true"  class="form-control" name="Id" ng-options="company as company.Company for company in companies track by company.Id" data-ng-model="item.Company"></select> 

</td>    
<td>
    <button type="button"  ng-click="saveUser($index,item)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save">
        </i>
    </button>        
    <button ng-click="reset($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="margin-right:0px">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
        </i>
    </button>
</td>
```

data-select-two data-allowclear="true" this directive is used for select2 implementation.We need both selected text and value  of selected item in the dropdown

Is there any solution for that ? or We  need a dropdown with clear button(inside the dropdown) for clearing the selected item in angularjs

I have implemented the dropdown using ui.slect2.But the model is not updating when we select new dropdown value

```
<select multiple data-ui-select2 class="form-control" name="ClientId" data-ng-model="item.Company">
        <option ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-selected="{{company.Id== item.Company.Id}}" value="{{company}}">{{company.Company}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: instead of using jquery select2 why don't use angular `ui-select2` which is angular version of select2

Comment: I have used ui-select2.But the model value is not updating when we select a new dropdown value

Comment: you need to assign `ng-model` to it

Comment: I have assigned the ng-model but it not binding the dropdown value to model

Comment: take a look at this http://www.bootply.com/vHj8Tv7uJu you will get an idea what you are missing